# CASE SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am curious if any one can tell me what I am doing wrong, or point me in the right direction. If someone can give me a hand, I would be thankful.

**Here is the question:**
Using the weblog table in your database create a query that will Group the IP addresses and display a sum of the number of requests by each IP address that had a return code (retcode) of greater than 300 order this query by the retcode field in descending order.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
SELECT COUNT(ipno) AS Number_of_Requests, retcode
FROM WebLog
GROUP BY ipno
HAVING retcode > 300
ORDER BY retcode DESC
```

Comment: Id advice you to take that picture down since you are showing ip adresses

Comment: Your query has nothing to do with `case`.  Further, the construct in a query is a `case` **expression**, not a `case` *statement*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is basically "wrong".  The problem is that it is asking for results at the ip level and then asking for you to order by the return code.  But a given IP could have more than one return code meeting the criteria.

One valid interpretation is that it really means "group by ip and retcode":

```
SELECT ipno, retcode, COUNT(ipno) AS Number_of_Requests
FROM WebLog
WHERE retcode) > 300
GROUP BY ipno
ORDER BY retcode DESC;
```

Another valid interpretation is that it means to order by the *maximum* retcode for each IP:

```
SELECT ipno, COUNT(ipno) AS Number_of_Requests
FROM WebLog
WHERE retcode > 300
GROUP BY ipno
ORDER BY MAX(retcode) DESC;
```

For this query, I would include `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT retcode)` to see a list of such codes.

To be honest, I suspect the write of the question intended for the `ORDER BY` to be by the number of log entries, and the phrasing just came out wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the filter clause to `where`. Also, it doesn't make sense to sort by retcode when you are grouping by IP.

If you really want to do that, use an aggregate function on retcode (say `max`):

```
SELECT ipno, COUNT(ipno) AS Number_of_Requests, max(retcode)
FROM WebLog
where retcode > 300
GROUP BY ipno
ORDER BY max(retcode) DESC
```